# How can I interact with my home router via a device on the local network using ssh?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, raspbian

I have a raspberry pi plugged into my router at home, running raspbian. Before I left for work I:

- Configured the router to forward ports 80 and 22 to the pi
- Configured dyndns

This all works, and I can access the pi using http and ssh. The problem is, I forgot to forward another port that I want to use! What I want to do is connect from the pi to my home router's web interface to forward the other port. The router interface is awful: heavy and graphical, and uses javascript. What should I do?

Comment: try `lynx` or use ssh proxy forward.

Comment: lynx: `To view the Web interface of your device, JavaScript must be supported and enabled on your browser! Please enable scripting and refresh your browser.`

Answer (score 3):

Setting up an SSH tunnel worked just fine. From work:

```
ssh -L 8080:192.168.1.254:80 <pi>
```

Then connecting to `localhost:8080` from my browser.